# function return promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Что вернёт функция, промис или строку?

Функция:

```
function f() {
  return get().then(function() {
    return "text";
  });
}
```

get() - это некая функция которая инкапсулирует какую-либо логику и возвращает промис.

Comment: Что такое `get()`?

Comment: Она не может вернуть строку хотя бы потому, что, вообще говоря, неизвестно, выполнится ли когда-нибудь это `return "text"`. А если выполнится, то неизвестно когда.

Comment: get() - это некая функция которая инкапсулирует какую-либо логику и возвращает промис.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция вернет результат выполнения метода `Promise.then()` - этот метод *всегда* возвращает новый **промис**.

```js
console.log(f().constructor.name);

function f() { return get().then(function() { return "text"; }); }
function get() { return Promise.resolve(); }
```

---

### Дополнение:

Написанное выше, относится к случаю когда коллбэк в `then` *выполняется*. Если же он не будет выполнен из-за ошибки/`reject`'а в функции `get()` - тогда `f()` вернет именно ее результат (тоже промис).

Единственный случай, когда `f()` может ***не*** вернуть промис - это случай когда выполнение прерывается в синхронном коде: до того, как `get()` вернет промис. То есть, когда `f()` не вернет вообще ничего, т.к. фактически не выполнится.
Пример:

```js
console.log(f().constructor.name);

function f() { return get().then(function() { console.log('hello'); return "text"; }); }
function get() {
  there.is.no.spoon;  // тут будет ошибка выполнения
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Подобная ситуация исключена, если код `get` будет обернут в коллбэк промиса (потому что тогда код выполнится *асинхронно*, и `get()` вернет результат ***до*** его выполнения):

```js
console.log(f().constructor.name);

function f() { return get().then(function() { return "text"; }); }
function get() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    there.is.no.spoon;  // тут будет ошибка, и выполнение перейдет в callback ближайшего .catch()
    resolve();
  }); 
}
```

Comment: А если метод then не настанет (get() вернёт реджект), что тогда вернёт сама функция?

Comment: @user287120 Так вроде вполне однозначно же сказано: «этот метод _всегда_ возвращает новый **промис**».

Comment: @user287120, в случае `reject()`, или при ошибке выполнения в теле промиса - все равно будет возвращен промис... он возвращается ***до*** выполнения.

Comment: И конечно же, при ошибке/reject внутри `get()` - до `then` выполнение не дойдет. В этом случае, результатом `f()` будет промис который вернула `get()`.

Comment: Ещё есть вариант, что `get` возвращает не промис, а что-то в духе `{ then(x) { return x } }` :D

Comment: _Написанное выше, относится к случаю когда then выполняется_ - на самом деле именно `then` выполняется **всегда**

Comment: @Qwertiy, да... вариант велопромиса, я как-то не учел :)

Comment: @Grundy, честь спорить с Вами, предоставлена примеру кода №2 (тому, что с ошибкой выполнения). **p.s.:** Надеюсь, очевидно то, что в контексте данного вопроса, под выполнением `then` подразумевается выполнение его аргумента (коллбэка)...

Comment: @yar85, конечно не очевидно. очень часто путают саму функцию then и коллбэк. который в нее передает. Пример №2 ничего не доказывает, так как не относится к Promise и then. Если имелось ввиду что не выполнился success обработчик, то это вполне логично, если бы вторым параметром для then передался error обработчик, объяснение бы стало ошибочным.

Comment: Подбивая итог пришел к выводу что then вернет промис, не взирая на то что, колбек функция возвращает, в данном случае, строку.  Т.е. нету смысла что-то возвращать колбек функцией если результат все-равно проигнорится. Верно?

Comment: @Grundy, становится очевидно, если учитывать контекст (не вырывая ответ из него): предметом вопроса является конкретный пример кода, и он получил конкретное объяснение. Если же описывать каждый случай который неадекватен примеру (т.е. игнорируя предмет вопроса) - получится книга по JavaScript, а не ответ :)

Comment: @user287120, почему же "проигнорится"? Например, `f().then(console.log);` выведет в консоль возвращаемую строку.